# Vimeo Player SDK: event listener not working when using an iframe

Tags: javascript, events, iframe, sdk, vimeo

I am stuck... I am trying to have a Vimeo player that is responsive both horizontally and vertically (width:100vw;height:100vh) and that can also use the listener player.on() to show and hide navigation buttons. Using an iframe seem to prevent the use of player.on(). The code below shows that I can get one requirement working or the other, but not both.

```
<!-- With this code below, the video player is responsive both horizontally and vertically... but the previous and next arrows are not hidden when the video is played. player.on() is not passed -->

<div>
    <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?playsinline=0" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100vw;height:100vh" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>


    <div id="flex-nav" class="nav-shown">

        <div class="flex-prev"><a href="https://google.com"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path d="M0 12c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12s12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12-12 5.373-12 12zm7.58 0l5.988-5.995 1.414 1.416-4.574 4.579 4.574 4.59-1.414 1.416-5.988-6.006z"/></svg></a></div>
        
        <div class="flex-next"><a href="https://google.com"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-1.568 18.005l-1.414-1.415 4.574-4.59-4.574-4.579 1.414-1.416 5.988 5.995-5.988 6.005z"/></svg></a></div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

    player.on('play', function() {
        console.log('Played the video, previous and next arrows hidden');
        var element = document.getElementById("flex-nav");
        element.classList.remove("nav-shown");
        element.classList.add("nav-hidden");
    });

    player.on('pause', function() {
        console.log('Paused the video, previous and next arrows shown');
        var element = document.getElementById("flex-nav");
        element.classList.remove("nav-hidden");
        element.classList.add("nav-shown");
    });

    player.getVideoTitle().then(function(title) {
      console.log('title:', title);
    });
</script>
```

```
<!-- With this code below, the previous and next arrows are hidden when the video is played... but the video player is not responsive vertically -->

<div>
    <div id="sessionVideo"></div>
    
    <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>

    <div id="flex-nav" class="nav-shown">

        <div class="flex-prev"><a href="https://google.com"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path d="M0 12c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12s12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12-12 5.373-12 12zm7.58 0l5.988-5.995 1.414 1.416-4.574 4.579 4.574 4.59-1.414 1.416-5.988-6.006z"/></svg></a></div>
        
        <div class="flex-next"><a href="https://google.com"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-1.568 18.005l-1.414-1.415 4.574-4.59-4.574-4.579 1.414-1.416 5.988 5.995-5.988 6.005z"/></svg></a></div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var options = {
        id: '76979871',
        responsive: true,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        playsinline: false,
        speed: false,
    };

    var player = new Vimeo.Player('sessionVideo', options);

    player.on('play', function() {
        console.log('Played the video, previous and next arrows hidden');
        var element = document.getElementById("flex-nav");
        element.classList.remove("nav-shown");
        element.classList.add("nav-hidden");       
    });

    player.on('pause', function() {
        console.log('Paused the video, previous and next arrows shown');
        var element = document.getElementById("flex-nav");
        element.classList.remove("nav-hidden");
        element.classList.add("nav-shown");
    });

    player.getVideoTitle().then(function(title) {
      console.log('title:', title);
    });
</script>
```

```
<!-- Both codes above use this CSS -->

<style>
    .nav-hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-shown {
        display: flex;  
    }
    #flex-nav {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    #flex-nav > div {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 50vh;
    }
    .flex-prev {
        left: 10px;
    }
    .flex-next {
        right: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use an iframe and update its src="" by javascript.